# Calculating System Login Frequency

Tags: algorithm, web, authentication, frequency

Dear StackOverflow community,

I'm trying to come up with a way to calculate the login frequency of users on my web application.

In my database, I'm recording the total number of times a user has logged in successfully till date, and the last login date and time.

Could you suggest an algorithm or a formula that could utilize the above data to come up with a login frequency percentage.

If not, what type of data shall I be capturing in order to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Why not store all of the logins, indexed by user id then time? Then you have a lot of options.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thank you David, that's actually a very viable option. However I still need to come up with some formula or query to get my answer.